# TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable using RL Classifiers

Tags: python, methods, syntax-error

I am working on a classification problem using Reinforcement Learning using the link https://github.com/gcamfer/Anomaly-ReactionRL/blob/master/Notebooks/AE_RL_awid.ipynb
I am facing error in the part of code shown below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
      
   
    
    # Train batch
    batch_size = 1
    # batch of memory ExpRep
    minibatch_size = 10
    ExpRep = True
    
    iterations_episode = 100
  
    # Initialization of the enviroment
    env = RLenv("train",batch_size=batch_size,
                iterations_episode=iterations_episode)    
    # obs_size = size of the state
    obs_size = env.data_shape[1]-len(env.all_attack_names)
    
    #num_episodes = int(env.data_shape[0]/(iterations_episode)/10)
    num_episodes = 100
    
    '''
    Definition for the defensor agent.
    '''
    defender_valid_actions = list(range(len(env.attack_types))) # only detect type of attack
    defender_num_actions = len(defender_valid_actions)    
    
    
    def_epsilon = 1 # exploration
    min_epsilon = 0.01 # min value for exploration
    def_gamma = 0.001
    def_decay_rate = 0.999
    
    def_hidden_size = 100
    def_hidden_layers = 2
    
    def_learning_rate = .01
    
    defender_agent = DefenderAgent(defender_valid_actions,obs_size,"EpsilonGreedy",
                          epoch_length = iterations_episode,
                          epsilon = def_epsilon,
                          min_epsilon = min_epsilon,
                          decay_rate = def_decay_rate,
                          gamma = def_gamma,
                          hidden_size=def_hidden_size,
                          hidden_layers=def_hidden_layers,
                          minibatch_size = minibatch_size,
                          mem_size = 1000,
                          learning_rate=def_learning_rate,
                          ExpRep=ExpRep)
    #Pretrained defender
    #defender_agent.model_network.model.load_weights("models/type_model.h5")    
    
    '''
    Definition for the attacker agent.
    In this case the exploration is better to be greater
    The correlation sould be greater too so gamma bigger
    '''
    attack_valid_actions = list(range(len(env.attack_names)))
    attack_num_actions = len(attack_valid_actions)
    
    att_epsilon = 1
    min_epsilon = 0.99 # min value for exploration

    att_gamma = 0.001
    att_decay_rate = 0.99
    
    att_hidden_layers = 1
    att_hidden_size = 100
    
    att_learning_rate = 0.2
    
    attacker_agent = AttackAgent(attack_valid_actions,obs_size,"EpsilonGreedy",
                          epoch_length = iterations_episode,
                          epsilon = att_epsilon,
                          min_epsilon = min_epsilon,
                          decay_rate = att_decay_rate,
                          gamma = att_gamma,
                          hidden_size=att_hidden_size,
                          hidden_layers=att_hidden_layers,
                          minibatch_size = minibatch_size,
                          mem_size = 1000,
                          learning_rate=att_learning_rate,
                          ExpRep=ExpRep)
    
        
    
    # Statistics
    att_reward_chain = []
    def_reward_chain = []
    att_loss_chain = []
    def_loss_chain = []
    def_total_reward_chain = []
    att_total_reward_chain = []
    
    # Print parameters
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Total epoch: {} | Iterations in epoch: {}"
          "| Minibatch from mem size: {} | Total Samples: {}|".format(num_episodes,
                         iterations_episode,minibatch_size,
                         num_episodes*iterations_episode))
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Dataset shape: {}".format(env.data_shape))
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Attacker parameters: Num_actions={} | gamma={} |" 
          " epsilon={} | ANN hidden size={} | "
          "ANN hidden layers={}|".format(attack_num_actions,
                             att_gamma,att_epsilon, att_hidden_size,
                             att_hidden_layers))
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Defense parameters: Num_actions={} | gamma={} | "
          "epsilon={} | ANN hidden size={} |"
          " ANN hidden layers={}|".format(defender_num_actions,
                              def_gamma,def_epsilon,def_hidden_size,
                              def_hidden_layers))
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    # Main loop
    attacks_by_epoch = []
    attack_labels_list = []
    for epoch in range(num_episodes):
        start_time = time.time()
        att_loss = 0.
        def_loss = 0.
        def_total_reward_by_episode = 0
        att_total_reward_by_episode = 0
        # Reset enviromet, actualize the data batch with random state/attacks
        states = env.reset()
        
        # Get actions for actual states following the policy
        attack_actions = attacker_agent.act(states)
        states = env.get_states(attack_actions)    
        
        done = False
       
        attacks_list = []
        # Iteration in one episode
        for i_iteration in range(iterations_episode):
            
            attacks_list.append(attack_actions[0])
            # apply actions, get rewards and new state
            act_time = time.time()  
            defender_actions = defender_agent.act(states)
            #Enviroment actuation for this actions
            next_states,def_reward, att_reward,next_attack_actions, done = env.act(defender_actions,attack_actions)
            # If the epoch*batch_size*iterations_episode is largest than the df

            
            attacker_agent.learn(states,attack_actions,next_states,att_reward,done)
            defender_agent.learn(states,defender_actions,next_states,def_reward,done)
            
            act_end_time = time.time()
            
            # Train network, update loss after at least minibatch_learns
            if ExpRep and epoch*iterations_episode + i_iteration >= minibatch_size:
                def_loss += defender_agent.update_model()
                att_loss += attacker_agent.update_model()
            elif not ExpRep:
                def_loss += defender_agent.update_model()
                att_loss += attacker_agent.update_model()
                

            update_end_time = time.time()

            # Update the state
            states = next_states
            attack_actions = next_attack_actions
            
            
            # Update statistics
            def_total_reward_by_episode += np.sum(def_reward,dtype=np.int32)
            att_total_reward_by_episode += np.sum(att_reward,dtype=np.int32)
        
        attacks_by_epoch.append(attacks_list)
        # Update user view
        def_reward_chain.append(def_total_reward_by_episode) 
        att_reward_chain.append(att_total_reward_by_episode) 
        def_loss_chain.append(def_loss)
        att_loss_chain.append(att_loss) 

        
        end_time = time.time()
        print("\r\n|Epoch {:03d}/{:03d}| time: {:2.2f}|\r\n"
                "|Def Loss {:4.4f} | Def Reward in ep {:03d}|\r\n"
                "|Att Loss {:4.4f} | Att Reward in ep {:03d}|"
                .format(epoch, num_episodes,(end_time-start_time), 
                def_loss, def_total_reward_by_episode,
                att_loss, att_total_reward_by_episode))
        
        
        print("|Def Estimated: {}| Att Labels: {}".format(env.def_estimated_labels,
              env.def_true_labels))
        attack_labels_list.append(env.def_true_labels)
```

and the error I am facing is

**TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could state in which line the error occurs.

Comment: @MichaelHodel most probably this part of code
```  # Initialization of the enviroment
    env = RLenv("train",batch_size=batch_size,
                iterations_episode=iterations_episode)    ```